# "Add AppEngine Backend" missing in Android Studio 0.8.2?

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

Is it possible that the function to generate AppEngine backend went missing from the submenu (Google Cloud Tools)? Or is it some new feature that requires me to do some setup first?

When I download major release (0.8.0) on web it's there. But when Android Studio gives me notice to update to 0.8.2 it's gone.

Comment: Would like to know answer to that question too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using Android studio but GAE backends are being phased out and replaced with modules.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting

Comment: Well.. generate backend is bound to disappear since backends are deprecated and being replaced with modules.

Comment: The link in my answer points to the docs for migrating from backends to modules. Best I can do...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you now have to create new module like File > New > Module > App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Mesaging